# Is there a possibility to export/backup the settings of PCmanFM in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, backup, shortcuts, pcmanfm

I add a lot of shortcuts to my file manager `pcmanfm`, I am referring to the shortcuts in the left panel of the window, and would like to backup those.

Comment: You just want to back up some shortcuts? Are they all in the same folder?

Comment: Are manually added shortcuts for PCmanFM stored in a certain folder? If so, which one is it? Then I would just copy this folder to my backup every now and then.

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by pcmanfm short cuts, I thought you were adding short cuts to the desktop for locations in the file manger, can you provide a screenshot of what you mean by `shortcuts`?

Comment: PCmanFM is the filmanager of Lubuntu. I can add shortscuts to quickly access certain folders. They are aded in the actual filemanager window on the left side. There are also default shortcuts for "home"  etc. I want to backup the settings of PCmanFM so that I can import all shortcuts on another machine if I want to.

Comment: I guess you mean "bookmarks". See ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks. Don't ask why they're stored in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/ even when pcmanfm is still a gtk2 app! I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: Yes, bookmarks, I am sorry. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Ben, If you are saying @DKBose comment work as a solution for you, please say so they can convert it to an answer

Comment: @DKBose answered my question, please convert it to an answer. My upvote is held back because my reputation is low.

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts appearing in the side pane are termed "bookmarks" in PCManFM. These are stored in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` even though the version of PCManFM installed by default in Lubuntu 14.04 is gtk-2.0.

By the way, I use this alias when I want to find what's recently changed in my home folder:

```
alias 5m='find ~/ ! -path "/home/dkb/.mozilla/*"  ! -path "/home/dkb/.cache/*" ! -path "/home/dkb/.config/google-chrome/*" ! -path "/home/dkb/.config/libreoffice/4/user/*" ! -path "/home/dkb/.dropbox/*" ! -name "recently-used.xbel" -mmin -5 -type f -ls'
```

It lists files that have been created or modified in the last 5 min but excludes certain folders and files that I'm not interested in knowing about.

So if I add a bookmark to PCManFM's side pane and immediately run `5m`, this is what I see:

```
$ 5m
7209279    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 dkb    dkb         578 Jan  8 21:36 /home/dkb/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
7739601    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 dkb    dkb         122 Jan  8 21:35 /home/dkb/.config/kupfer/config-kupfer.plugin.favorites-v1.pickle
7739514    4 -rw-rw-r--   1 dkb    dkb          36 Jan  8 21:35 /home/dkb/.config/kupfer/config-kupfer.plugin.triggers-v1.pickle
7739653    8 -rw-rw-r--   1 dkb    dkb        4726 Jan  8 21:35 /home/dkb/.config/kupfer/mnemonics.pickle
$
```